# Laravel typescript:transform generates 0 PHP to TS files

Tags: typescript, laravel, laravel-artisan

I came back to work with Laravel/Artisan after a long time, and this case, I am trying to apply the typescript-transformer for migrating the PHP SDK into its corresponding TS SDK. Even there is someone else and also I am about to try the manual code migration rather this automated yet riskier approach, this usage of typescript-transformer can still hold as a good reference for the comparison of the code migration.

I followed the straightforward step as followed in the link. After the first trial that I was unsure why config of typescript-transformer was not outputted, its because my machien needed the PHP curl extension for Laravel setup, so I then installed to fix it.

https://spatie.be/docs/typescript-transformer/v2/laravel/installation-and-setup

However, as I run the typescript transformer to test the migrations and looks for possible solutions, I couldn't understand why it is not generating. Even I removed the package and reinstall it. At least, I tried creating the default Laravel project without the PHP SDK, with just purely auto-generated Laravel codes, and redoed the steps but still not being able to generate it anything.

Here is the typescript-transformer config

```
<?php

return [
    /*
     * The paths where typescript-transformer will look for PHP classes
     * to transform, this will be the `app` path by default.
     */

    'auto_discover_types' => [
        app_path()
    ],

    /*
     * Collectors will search for classes in the `auto_discover_types` paths and choose the correct
     * transformer to transform them. By default, we include a DefaultCollector which will search
     * for @typescript annotated and ![TypeScript] attributed classes to transform.
     */

    'collectors' => [
        Spatie\TypeScriptTransformer\Collectors\DefaultCollector::class,
        Spatie\TypeScriptTransformer\Collectors\EnumCollector::class,
    ],

    /*
     * Transformers take PHP classes(e.g., enums) as an input and will output
     * a TypeScript representation of the PHP class.
     */

    'transformers' => [
        Spatie\LaravelTypeScriptTransformer\Transformers\SpatieStateTransformer::class,
        Spatie\TypeScriptTransformer\Transformers\SpatieEnumTransformer::class,
        Spatie\TypeScriptTransformer\Transformers\DtoTransformer::class,
    ],

    /*
     * In your classes, you sometimes have types that should always be replaced
     * by the same TypeScript representations. For example, you can replace a
     * Datetime always with a string. You define these replacements here.
     */

    'default_type_replacements' => [
        DateTime::class => 'string',
        DateTimeImmutable::class => 'string',
        Carbon\CarbonImmutable::class => 'string',
        Carbon\Carbon::class => 'string',
    ],

    /*
     * The package will write the generated TypeScript to this file.
     */

    'output_file' => resource_path('types/generated.d.ts'),

    /*
     * When the package is writing types to the output file, a writer is used to
     * determine the format. By default, this is the `TypeDefinitionWriter`.
     * But you can also use the `ModuleWriter` or implement your own.
     */

    'writer' => Spatie\TypeScriptTransformer\Writers\TypeDefinitionWriter::class,

    /*
     * The generated TypeScript file can be formatted. We ship a Prettier formatter
     * out of the box: `PrettierFormatter` but you can also implement your own one.
     * The generated TypeScript will not be formatted when no formatter was set.
     */

    'formatter' => null,

    /*
     * Enums can be transformed into types or native TypeScript enums, by default
     * the package will transform them to types.
     */

    'transform_to_native_enums' => false,
];
```

```
 php artisan typescript:transform
+-----------+-------------------+
| PHP class | TypeScript entity |
+-----------+-------------------+
Transformed 0 PHP types to TypeScript
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm having exactly the same problem.
What is your PHP version?
I'm running the script on windows 11 with PHP version 8.2.7
I've also tried several approaches without success:

- set up a project with only "spatie/typescript-transformer" v2 installed... 0 TypeScript code generated.
- create a Laravel project and publish the configuration of "spatie/laravel-typescript-transformer" v2... 0 TypeScript code generated.

```bash
+-----------+-------------------+
| PHP class | TypeScript entity |
+-----------+-------------------+
Transformed 0 PHP types to TypeScript
```

- I've tested both approaches to commenting my PHP classes.

```php
/** @typescript */
```

and

```php
#[TypeScript]
```

I'm a little desperate